# Defining a model properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have different types of profile schema's defined in my project:

- mentor_profile
- partner_admin_profile
- district_admin_profile

I want to store these as references in a single key in a user schema defined like so...I didn't want to make them all separate keys because if I need to populate them I feel like I would do unnecessary logic that I can avoid if I just define them in a single key.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
profile:{
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "partner_admin_profile", <--- Is it possible to store profiles to this dynamically?

}
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use refpath and then give dynamically value to refpath...
Like this.
.........

```
profile : 
{ 
category: String, 
profile_id: { type: String, refPath: 'profile.category'}
}
```

...........
In category you have to pass your category like patner_admin_profile..